# Cauchy–Schwarz-like inequality justifying the maximum of Sharpe ratio.

Tags: inequality, optimization, finance, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let ${\bf \Delta}=(\delta_1,\,\ldots,\,\delta_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus(0,\,\ldots,\,0)$, ${\bf 1}=(1,\,\ldots,\,1)_{1\times n}$ and $\bf 1\Delta$$^T=0$, where $T$ denotes transpose.

Let ${\bf \mu}=(\mu_1-r_f,\,\ldots,\,\mu_n-r_f)$, where
$\mu_1,\,\ldots,\,\mu_n$ are expected returns of some random returns $r_1,\,\ldots,\,r_n$ and $r_f$ denotes the risk-free return rate.

Let $\Sigma$ denote the covariance matrix of $r_1,\,\ldots,\,r_n$ and $\Sigma^{-1}$ its inverse. We assume that $\Sigma^{-1}$ exists.

Can you show that
$$
\left({\bf \Delta \mu}^T\right)^2<{\bf \mu}\Sigma^{-1}{\bf \mu}^T\,{\bf \Delta}\Sigma{\bf \Delta}^T
$$
for all such $\bf \Delta$?

Such inequality appears trying to justify that

$$
{\bf W}^T=(w_1,\,\ldots,\,w_n)^T=\frac{\Sigma^{-1}{\bf \mu}^T}{{\bf 1}\Sigma^{-1}{\bf \mu}^T}
$$
maximizes the Sharpe ratio

$$
\frac{\bf W \mu^T}{\sqrt{{\bf W}\Sigma{\bf W}^T}},\text{ when } {\bf 1}{\bf W}^T=1.
$$

Comment: Can you elaborate what your Sharpe ratio has to do with [the one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharpe_ratio) most people are familiar with? A one-to-one mapping of your notation to the one in the link would be ideal.

Comment: It is the same Sharpe ratio. If r_1, ... r_n are random returns of risky assets A_1, ... A_n, then the expected return of portfolio B=w_1A_1+...+w_nA_n, w_1+...+w_n=1 is Er_B=(w_1, ..., w_n)(Er_1, ..., Er_n)^T and variance \sigma_B^2=(w_1, ..., w_n) \Sigma (w_1, ..., w_n)^T. Observing that r_f=r_f(w_1+...w_n) we get that the Sharpe ratio of portfolio B is as provided.

Comment: Managed to prove on my own.

Comment: @FancierofMathematica you may post the proof as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the covariance matrix of non-degenarate random variables is positively defined, then
$$
\left({\bf 1}\Sigma^{-1}{\bf\mu}^T\right)^2{\bf W}\Sigma\bf{W}^T>0
$$
for any collection of weights $\bf W$. By taking
$$
{\bf W}^T=\frac{\Sigma^{-1}{\bf\mu}^T}{{\bf1}\Sigma^{-1}{\bf\mu}^T}+{\bf \Delta}^T
$$
we get
$$
\left({\bf 1}\Sigma^{-1}{\bf\mu}^T\right)^2{\bf W}\Sigma\bf{W}^T
={\bf \Delta}\Sigma{\bf \Delta}^T\left({\bf 1}\Sigma^{-1}{\bf\mu}^T\right)^2
+2{\bf \Delta}{\bf\mu}\left({\bf 1}\Sigma^{-1}{\bf\mu}^T\right)
+{\bf\mu}\Sigma^{-1}{\bf\mu}^T>0.
$$
Recalling that $ax^2+bx+c>0$ implies $b^2-4ac<0$ we get the desired inequality.